# Laravel: Controller function to update the data

Tags: php, laravel

How can I update the data of a foreach?

The data is rendered like here:

```
@foreach ($translation as $locale)
      <div class="form-group">
          <label><strong>Locale</strong></label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="locale" name="locale" rows="1" disabled>{{$locale->locale}}</textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Title</strong></label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="title" name="title" rows="1">{{$locale->title}}</textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Caption</strong></label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="caption" name="caption" rows="1">{{$locale->caption}}</textarea>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

And I want to update the values on the data base using a controller function.

I know how to update the single values, but with a foreach, I don't have any idea.

Yesterday I posted another question, but maybe isn't formulated correctly and nobody gives me an answer. I post it here cause maybe you have more information.

Thanks a lot, any help will be really appreciated.

[Laravel: How to update array in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549035/laravel-how-to-update-array-in-controller?noredirect=1#comment78059925_45549035)

Comment: If I understood correctly, your form depends of how many `locale` you have define ? Like "en", "fr", etc. ?

Comment: Yes! @Nenroz this is why I use a foreach :) Maybe know how to do it?

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer You can use array of input fields and foreach loop.  I've added answer, take a moment to view it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your `foreach` is surrounded by a `<form>`.

I propose this:

- Change the `name` attributes of your fields into an array with ID of the current locale: `name="locale[{{ $locale->id }}][title]"`
- In your controller, use a `foreach` to update each locale, like this:

```php
$locales = $request->input('locale');

foreach ($locales as $id => $attr)
{
    $locale = Locale::find($id);
    $locale->title = $attr['title'];
    // ...
    $locale->save();
}
```

Comment: Working! Know how to pass a input value when is disabled?

Comment: Instead of `disabled`, use `readonly`. `readonly` and `disabled` are the same, but have one difference: `readonly` fields sent their value, while `disabled` ones don't.

Comment: If you can, check this question. Maybe you can help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567009/laravel-controller-function-to-delete-the-data

Answer (score 2):

You should create a function that allowed to receive array of values

On your view, You need to make all your form element name as array.

```
@foreach ($translation as $locale)
<div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>Locale</strong></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="locale[]" rows="1">{{$locale->locale}}</textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>Title</strong></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="title[]" rows="1">{{$locale->title}}</textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>Caption</strong></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="caption[]" rows="1">{{$locale->caption}}</textarea>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="locale_id[]" value="{{$locale->id}}"> // Make sure you add the id
@endforeach
```

Then on your controller, You should handle those arrays

```
function update(){
    $locale_id = $request->locale_id;
    $locale = $request->locale ;
    $caption =  $request->caption;
    $title=  $request->title;
    foreach($locale_id as $key => $value){
         DB::table('project_translations')->where('id', $value )->update([
             'locale' => $locale[$key],
             'title' => $title[$key],
             'caption' => $caption[$key],
         ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mate @RomnickSusa let me ask you some things. The table is called project_translations and the fields are: id, locale, project_id, title and caption. For each project, i create two translations one with locale 'en' and other with locale 'es'. Maybe i'm confused, but I think the code isn't correct.

Comment: It should be working fine. How did you say that it isn't working? Is there some kind of error?

Comment: Well i'm checking your code and for example, don't have any save(), maybe you forget it?

Comment: The hidden field `name` attribute misses an "e" (`locale_id[]`, and not `local_id[]`), but it sounds good to me. `save()` is not the only method to update the database, so it should work with the `update()` method.

Comment: It's working! Thanks. Anyway, know how to pass a input value with the 'disabled'?

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer Can you provide the name of your model so i can revise my answer?

Comment: It's solved with readonly! Maybe you can help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567009/laravel-controller-function-to-delete-the-data

Comment: Okay ill try to read it. Please mark as accepted if you are satisfied with my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `name` attributes to array type like

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="locale" name="locale[]" rows="1" disabled>{{$locale->locale}}</textarea>
.... 
....
```

And add array input field for id inside loop like,

```
<input name="id[]" value="{{$locale->id}}" hidden>
```

Now, In controller post function,

```
public function update(Request $request){
    foreach($request->id as $key => $value){

        // Find record to update with Model as your table model

        $record = Model::find($value);

        $record->locale = $request->locale[$key];
        $record->title = $request->title[$key];
        $record->caption = $request->caption[$key];

        $record->save();
    }
}
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: Hi mate! @SagarGautam it's working! Know how to pass a value with input is disabled?

Comment: It's solved with the readonly;) Maybe you can help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567009/laravel-controller-function-to-delete-the-data

Comment: @GolamSorwar Pleasure ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this :

```
@foreach ($translation as $locale)
      <div class="form-group">
          <label><strong>Locale</strong></label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="locale" name="locale[]" rows="1" disabled>{{$locale->locale}}</textarea>
       <input type="hidden" name="locale[]" value="{{$locale->locale}}">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Title</strong></label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="title" name="title[]" rows="1">{{$locale->title}}</textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Caption</strong></label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="caption" name="caption[]" rows="1">{{$locale->caption}}</textarea>
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" name="localId[]" value="{{$locale->id}}">
@endforeach



public function update(Request $request){
    foreach($request->localId as $key => $value){
         DB::table('DbName')->where('id', $value )->update([
             'locale' => $request->locale[$key],
             'title' => $request->title[$key],
             'caption' => $request->caption[$key],
         ]);
    }
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: Working! know how to pass a value when input is disabled?

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer I was taken hidden field for locale value so check and try it

Comment: Solved with readonly ;)! Maybe you can help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567009/laravel-controller-function-to-delete-the-data