# Laravel: Controller function to delete the data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I will explain first the tables and how code works

**Tables**

I have:

- projects with fields: id, slug, order, public, pathheader and pathhome.
- project_translations with fields: id, locale, project_id, title and caption.
- clients with fields: id, name, slug and priority.
- client_project with fields: id, client_id and project_id

**How the code works**

When I create a project, I create two project translation too (one for each locale, ex: 'es', 'en'). and then I select a client and this makes the relation client_project.

When I delete the project, I delete at the same time the project_translations which have the same project_id and the client_project row where project_id is the same.

**What I want**

When I delete the client, delete the row which field client_id have the same value (this is working) and then, delete the projects and projects_translations of the projects which have relation with the client i deleted.

**How my function looks for the moment**

```
public function destroyClient($id) //Destruir cliente y todo lo relacionado de la bbdd
    {
        $cliente = Client::find($id); 
        $cliente->delete(); //delete the client
        DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->delete(); //delete the client_project relations which field client_id is the same that the client i just deleted.

        return redirect()->route('admin.clients');
    }
```

Comment: So, problem is client is deleted successfully but record in `client_project` and `project_transalation` doesn't deleted ?

Comment: have you tried `$cliente->projects()->delete();` ?

Comment: With this code for the moment i just delete the client and the client_project relations. I need to delete the project and project_translation @SagarGautam

Comment: you need to make database optimized. Make correct relations and cascading it will be easier to delete records on multiple tables

Comment: Yes @MisaGH and isn't working.

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer Can you add relationship nature like one-to-one or one-to-many etc among the tables.

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567549/5013099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will first get all the projects related to client. And then will delete all projects of a client through loop.

```
public function destroyClient($id) 
{
    $cliente = Client::find($id); 
    $cliente->delete(); //delete the client

    // get list of all projects of client
    $projects = DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->get();

    DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->delete(); 

    // delete all projects of client
    foreach($projects as $project)
    {
        DB::table('projects')->where('id',$project->id)->delete();

        DB::table('project_translations')->where('project_id',$project->id)->delete(); 
    }    

    return redirect()->route('admin.clients');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this can help you

```
public function destroyClient($id) //Destruir cliente y todo lo relacionado de la bbdd
    {
        $cliente = Client::find($id);
        $cliente_project = DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id', $id)->first();
        $project_id = $cliente_project->project_id;
        $cliente->delete(); //delete the client
        DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->delete(); //delete the client_project relations which field client_id is the same that the client i just deleted.

        DB::table('projects')->where('id',$project_id)->delete();
        DB::table('project_translations')->where('project_id',$project_id)->delete();

        return redirect()->route('admin.clients');
    }
```

Maybe a better way is using foreing keys

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this :

```
public function destroyClient($id) //Destruir cliente y todo lo relacionado de la bbdd
{
    $cliente = Client::find($id); 
    $cliente->delete(); //delete the client
    $project = DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->first();
    DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->delete(); 


    DB::table('projects')->where('id',$project->project_id)->delete();

    DB::table('project_translations')->where('project_id',$project->project_id)->delete(); 


    return redirect()->route('admin.clients');
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!